# ¿Que significan estas lineas en proyecto Django en Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, linux-mint

Descarguè el siguiente proyecto Django de Github [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/OverLord48/SystemFac) y todo parecia ir bien, instalè python, el entorno de desarrollo, pip, etc. Pero al querer iniciarlo para poder visualizarlo con `python3 manage.py runserver` me encuentro con este problema en la consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué investigaste?

Comment: Hola @fedorqui 'SO deja de dañar', hice todo al pie de la letra como dice https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment quise buscar en youtube alguna explicacion mas especifica sobre github con proyectos django, pero no hay mucha informacion

Comment: dale a [edit] y pon texto en lugar de imágenes para que podamos ayudar mejor. Leer [ask] puede dar buenas pistas también. Fíjate que al fin y al cabo lo que le falla es una librería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta de buscar la solución a un error, es identificar por consola qué clase de error es. Allí el error es el siguiente: `ModuleNotFoundError: Not module named psycopg2`. Esto, en vez de las imágenes es lo que debes incluir en tus preguntas para que sea más fácil darte las respuesta.

El módulo `psycopg2` sirve para administrar postgres con python. Este problema se soluciona en linux primero instalando las dependencias:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2
```

Y luego en dentro de tu virtualenv ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Luego de correr nuevamente el proceso, ya no debería devolverte ese error.